# How to deal with label that not included in training set when doing prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning

For example, using supervise learning to classify 5 different people face.
But when test on 6th people face that not in training set, the model will still predict it within the 5 people.
How to let the model predict the 6th and onwards people face as unknown when the model doesn't train them before?

Comment: You can use additional class "unknown" during classification. Fill it with negative samples (random faces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a certain threshold for prediction the known classes. Your model should predict from the known classes only if it predicts it with a certain threshold value, otherwise, it will be classified as *unknown*.

The other (and less preferable) way to deal with this problem is to have another class called *unknown* even during training and put some random faces as corresponding examples of this class.

Comment: I think set a threshold for prediction is the answer that I want. Is there any standard to set a threshold?

Comment: Now I have a big problem, currerntly I am doing diagnosis codes classification by using discharge summary.
Some diagnosis code have no enough number of data, it force me to ignore it in training even though it was a mistake to ignore them.
For instance, heart diseaase has 4 type of diagnosis code (e.g. A, B, C, D), the number of discharge summary was significantly imbalance (e.g. size of C is less and D has no data), then I only train model with two of it (e.g. A and B). Now I want the model recognize C and D test data as unknown rather than predicted as A and B.

Comment: Trying different values for threshold and seeing the accuracy changes on validation set is the only way to go about it.

Comment: For your other problem, "Imputing the missing values" is the way to go. There are various imputation methods. In my experience, a Random Forest based method called *MissForest* works well, and comes bundled as a R package. If your application is precision diagnosis, and if you have lots of missing values, be careful because you are just estimating the missing values, and will be training your model on  semi-synthesized data.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a certain threshold for prediction the known classes. Your model should predict from the known classes only if it predicts it with a certain threshold value, otherwise, it will be classified as unknown.
this option do not work